# Docker Compose build then package.json no such file or directory, open

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

**my folder list**

root : docekr-compose.yml

1depth folder: /xxxxx/Docker

1depth folder: /xxxxx/sources....

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '3.7'

services:
  clientBackend:
    container_name: clientbackend
    image: clientbackend-image
    build:
      context: 3kings_client_backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - 3kingsnet
    volumes: 
      - .:/clientbackend

volumes:
  data:
    driver: local

networks:
  3kingsnet:
    driver: bridge
```

**Docker File**

```
    FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /clientbackend
COPY . /clientbackend
RUN ls
RUN npm install --silent
ENV NODE_ENV=local
RUN ls
CMD ["npm","run","local"]
```

build then

```
Attaching to clientbackend
clientbackend    | npm ERR! code ENOENT
clientbackend    | npm ERR! syscall open
clientbackend    | npm ERR! path /clientbackend/package.json
clientbackend    | npm ERR! errno -2
clientbackend    | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/clientbackend/package.json'
clientbackend    | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
clientbackend    | npm ERR! enoent
clientbackend    | 
clientbackend    | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
clientbackend    | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-24T04_39_57_661Z-debug.log
clientbackend exited with code 254
```

OTL..

Comment: Why bother copying stuff into `/clientbackend` if you're just going to mount a volume over it?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to use nodemon.